# I try to create link for payment (pmt_link), start the routine to track payment but routine is a loop I can not return link to browser

Tags: ajax, flask, python-asyncio

from flask import request, jsonify
import asyncio
from functions impprt pmt_link, order_status

@app.route('/addToBasket', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def basket_data():

```
if request.method == "POST":
    data = request.get_json()
    action = data\['action'\]
    if action == 'paymentLink':
        link = pmt_link(data)
        result = jsonify(link)
        order_status(data)
    return result
```

> I tried asyncio  but it still did not work for me
>
>  `!  !`

Comment: You need to clarify several things.  (1) There is a problem with formatting of the question.  Please proofread it and fix it.  (2) A routine is not a loop, although it may contain a loop.  If the routine is an infinite loop, then it will never return.  From such a routine you cannot "return link to browser" because there is no return at all.  Otherwise, all Python routines return an object.  So please clarify what your problem is.  (3) If you need help with asyncio, please show us what you tried.  "Did not work for me" doesn't tell us anything, and is never going to get you any help here.

Comment: @PaulCornelius, thank you for the reply. The routine "order_status()" is a loop in my case, and it checks the status of the payment. Depending on the status it either will stop or continue checking. But status checking only makes sense if the link have been sent. And to send the link  the return statement using ajax have to be send. But once there is a "return" the second procedure will not start.